# error C2227: left of '->width' must point to class/struct/union/generic type, raycasting rendering

Tags: c++, raycasting

I have trouble with error C2227, here is my code

I have no idea how to have acces to volume->voxel->width from MyWindow, I have to get a width of volume data.

I have edited, a post. I created a pointer in Volume type but it do not worked too.

MyWindow.cpp

```
  #include "MainWindow.h"

#include <QFileDialog>

#include <QPainter>
#include "Volume.h"


MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
    : QMainWindow(parent), m_Volume(0), m_VectorField(0)
{
    m_Ui = new Ui_MainWindow();
    m_Ui->setupUi(this);

    connect(m_Ui->actionOpen, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(openFileAction()));
    connect(m_Ui->actionClose, SIGNAL(triggered()), this, SLOT(closeAction()));






    float width = m_Ui->label->width();
    float height = m_Ui->label->height();




 (float i = 0; i < m_Volume->voxel->width; i++) // HERE IS ERROR
    {
        m_Ui->label->width();
    }

    QPixmap map(width, height);
    map.fill(QColor(255, 0, 0, 0));








}
```

volume.h

```
// Voxel
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Voxel
{
    public:

        Voxel();
        Voxel(const Voxel &other);
        Voxel(const float value);

        ~Voxel();


        // VOXEL VALUE

        void                    setValue(const float value);
        const float             getValue() const;


        // OPERATORS

        const bool              operator==(const Voxel &other) const;
        const bool              operator!=(const Voxel &other) const;
        const bool              operator>(const Voxel &other) const;
        const bool              operator>=(const Voxel &other) const;
        const bool              operator<(const Voxel &other) const;
        const bool              operator<=(const Voxel &other) const;

        const Voxel             operator+(const Voxel &other) const;
        const Voxel             operator-(const Voxel &other) const;
        const Voxel             operator*(const float &value) const;
        const Voxel             operator/(const float &value) const;

        const Voxel&            operator+=(const Voxel &other);
        const Voxel&            operator-=(const Voxel &other);
        const Voxel&            operator*=(const float &value);
        const Voxel&            operator/=(const float &value);


    private:

        float                   m_Value;

};


//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Volume
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

class Volume
{

    public:

        Volume();
        ~Volume();


        // VOLUME DATA

        const Voxel&            voxel(const int i) const;
        const Voxel&            voxel(const int x, const int y, const int z) const;
        const Voxel*            voxels() const;

        const int               width() const;
        const int               height() const;
        const int               depth() const;

        const int               size() const;

        bool                    loadFromFile(QString filename, QProgressBar* progressBar);


    private:

        std::vector<Voxel>      m_Voxels;

        int                     m_Width;
        int                     m_Height;
        int                     m_Depth;

        int                     m_Size;

};
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to be a [mcve].  This only needs a declaration of m_Volume, an assignment to it, and an attempt to access the width.  We also need the full definitions of all the relevant types.

Comment: I have, edited a post

Comment: Voxel doesn't have width as a member. Volume does. So shouldn't it be `m_Volume->width()` instead of `m_Volume->voxel->width`?

Comment: I am getting this with your solution: Unhandled exception at 0x0087C286 in Visualisierung1.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x00000010.

Comment: You didn't allocate space for `m_Volume` so that is understandable. The question is does `m_Volume` really need to be a pointer?

Comment: How other can I get acces to width()?

Comment: And can you show me how could I allocate the space?

Comment: `m_Volume = new Volume;` Although I expect you want to do something to initialize m_Volume before iterating over it. And we can't possibly guess what the something is.

Comment: I am doing it before when I am loading file to program. On the base of this file I am creating a Volume. And from this Volume I would like to get width value to do ray casting rendering.

Comment: Why are you using an -> on m_Volume . Is it a pointer to Volume class? If not then you should use m_Volume.width() that should work.

Comment: Then you can't do the loop that you are trying in MainWindow::MainWindow(). You probably want to use signals and slots to do whatever you wanted with m_Ui->label after m_Volume is set. I say do whatever you wanted because this makes no sense at all: `m_Ui->label->width();`